# Problem to generate the client generator component of API Patform with nuxt.js

Tags: symfony, nuxt.js, api-platform.com

I have an api-platform project.

https://localhost:8888/api does show the API documentation.

When i want to generate the client generator component with the command:

- `npx @api-platform/client-generator https://127.0.0.1:8000/api . --generator nuxt`

I have this response:

```
{
  api: Api { entrypoint: 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/api', resources: [] },
  error: {
    response: Response {
      size: 0,
      timeout: 0,
      [Symbol(Body internals)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(Response internals)]: [Object]
    }
  },
  response: Response {
    size: 0,
    timeout: 0,
    [Symbol(Body internals)]: { body: [PassThrough], disturbed: false, error: null },
    [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
      url: 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/api',
      status: 200,
      statusText: 'OK',
      headers: [Headers],
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  status: 200
}
```

No components have been generated and not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Hi, I'm not familiar with `client generator component`, what is it? What do you want to have at the end in your Nuxt app?

Comment: Theoretically, it generates all the components necessary to build a CRUD graphical interface. https://api-platform.com/docs/client-generator/nuxtjs/

Comment: Yes, I migrate my project in Heroku and I managed to generate the components. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the setup successfully on my side (until I got a CORS issue probably because I was using `https://demo.api-platform.com`).
Here is [my Github repo](https://github.com/kissu/api-platform-nuxt) for a working client side boilerplate'd Nuxt app that I've got.

Some things are questionable like the usage of Moment.js in 2022, the fact that this is a Nuxt app used as an SPA only (`ssr: false`), some not up to-date configuration like for [`nuxt-i18n` modules](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/setup/), the `components: false`, the fact that there are still some ESlint warnings/errors in the various files, the use of an additional `vue-i18n` package on top of `nuxt-i18n` but the setup looks kinda okay otherwise.

I mean, at the end it's kinda removing all the nice stuff from Nuxt to have a basic usual Vue.js app as an SPA but yeah, fine let's say.

There is this line in `entrypoint.js`

```js
export const ENTRYPOINT = 'https://demo.api-platform.com'
```

Maybe setting this one up to your own local address may work.
If it doesn't, maybe try to host it [on Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) or alike, a real hosted server is maybe needed. Otherwise, it could also be a migration/DB/any-other-backend issue.

It's not an issue on the Nuxt.js side itself at least.